# Will there be a move here

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Here is simplified code snippet:

```
void printArray(vector<int> arr)
{
    vector<int> temp_a = arr; //<<------- move here?
    for(int i = 0; i < temp_a.size(); ++i)
        cout << temp_a[i] << endl;
}
```

Will there be a move there?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why you think `arr` might be moved?

Comment: No. `arr` is an lvalue

Comment: Your simplified example might be a little *too* simplified. There's no need for the `temp_a` vector, and there's no need to not pass `arr` by value. I feel there's an underlying problem behind your question, but it's not talked about.

Comment: Do you *want* a move there?  `vector<int> temp_a = std::move(arr);` is how you do it.

Comment: There are no automatic move for last usage. The only automatic move is for `return var;` statement.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, the problem is absence of last use detection due to reference unsafety and lifetime issues. If compiler could effectively and generically implement last use detection, I'd expect an implied move here.

Comment: Don't spam in C++ version tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the move constructor of `std::vector` won't be used in that instance; the copy constructor will be used instead.

In general, moves don't happen implicitly, because every expression made of an identifier (*unqualified-id*) is an lvalue (e.g. `arr` is an lvalue). The move constructor accepts a `std::vector&&` rvalue reference, and that cannot bind to lvalues. As a result, the copy constructor is called.

The only exception to this rule is in a return statement:

```cpp
// if arr is a local variable, it will be moved implicitly here
return arr;
```

To move the vector in your case, you must use [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move):

```cpp
vector<int> temp_a = move(arr);
```

However, the whole function could also be simplified to:

```cpp
void printArray(const vector<int>& arr)
{
    for(int x : arr)
        cout << x << '\n';
}
```